# Get the "filename" and extension from a wget response

Tags: php, wget

Is there an easy way to get the filename and extension from a file downloaded via wget using PHP ?

The exact problem is. 
I am trying to access the facebook image of a user after they have accepted my facebook app.

```
//e.g
wget http://graph.facebook.com/663660516/picture
```

Therefore, I do not know the filename / extension of the downloaded file.

Comment: So you want to know how to get the name and extension of any file?

Comment: Can you provide us with more details? This is too vague.

Comment: Technically, you can't.  All you can do is guess based on the URL, or from the `Content-Disposition` header, if present.  Who knows what the actual file name on the remote server is.

Comment: added more detail. but no, I do not know the filename or extension

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  You are more likely to found help solving your problem if you can provide a more detailed question, and include what has or has not worked already for you.

Comment: In this particular case, do you expect `275781_663660516_1323021723_q` and `.jpg`?

Comment: it's probably 663660516.jpg, when the filename is the first segment of the url path, and the extension is always .jpg.

Comment: Can I assume the extension is always "jpg", as that would solve enough of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following I am able to get the filename:

```
<?php

ob_start();
passthru('wget http://graph.facebook.com/663660516/picture 2>&1');
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

if (preg_match('/saving to:.{4}([a-z0-9\.-_]*)/i', $out, $match)) {
    var_dump($match);
} else {
    echo "No match";
}
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(47) "Saving to: “275781_663660516_1323021723_q.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(33) "275781_663660516_1323021723_q.jpg"
}
```

From `$result[1]` you could then get the extension and name using [pathinfo()](http://php.net/pathinfo) or similar methods.

Note: the .{4} in the regex is to consume the special quote (`“`) character wget outputs around the file (at least on my system).  It registers as 3 bytes long in PHP and I cannot match it by character code so that is a bit of a hack in my opinion.  Also assumes the system language is english as it looks for `Saving to:` in the output.

Hope that helps.